# cannot read value from txt file using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am a beginner in Java and trying to learn the basics of `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. I was able to successfully write the data to the file but unable to read it. Here is my code. Could you please let me know, if I am missing something to read the data.

Application.java

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try(FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("testdata.txt")){

            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            MathematicalOperation mo = new MathematicalOperation();

            os.writeObject(mo);
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

ReadingFile.Java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class ReadDataFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    try(FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("testdata.txt")){
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
        MathematicalOperation mo= (MathematicalOperation) oi.readObject();
        System.out.println(mo);
        oi.close();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you have gott... please mention it

Comment: The file contains just a single line of text, "Learn File Streaming". @JafferWilson There is no error, the output I get is MathematicalOperation@eed1f14

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to read the content of the .txt file, just use FileInputStream class.

Also, it would be of great help if you coul

Answer (score 0):

While writing to the file "testdata.txt" you are passing object of MathematicalOperation class, you can set values of the class members before writing file (e.g. mo.setXXX()) and when you are reading that object from text file you can get those values using the return object of MathematicalOperation (e.g. mo.getXXX()) and before printing the object please override toString() method in your MathematicalOperation class to display the correct values of all fields of the class.